# Is this an iOS bug?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to test this line:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

on iPhone 6 Plus.

Seems to have no effect. The default separator is still shown. Works fine on iPhone 5. In both cases iOS 8.

Anyone faced this issue before? If yes, do you know any good solution around it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the [color of the separator](http://xcdoc://?url=developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/ios/1048/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html) to the color of the bottom of the cells.